# Trying to find variance: Float object is not iterable

Tags: python-2.7, sum, variance

I've been trying to code the Lomb-Scargle Periodogram in Python, but am having an error when I try to find variance. When I try to read each value of a list, in order, Python says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Periodogram.py", line 18, in periodogramTest
    variance = (sum(((magnitude[j]-mean)**2))/(len(magnitude)-1))   
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I'm not sure if the error here has to do with the way in which I am structuring the list, or the format of the equation itself. Here is my code:

```
import csv
import math

def periodogramTest():
    f=1/23
    omega = 2*3.14159265*f
    magnitude=[]
    with open ("hv878.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
        for row in datareader:
            mag=row[2]
            mag=eval(mag)
            magnitude.append(mag)
    map(float, magnitude[0:343])
    mean=sum(magnitude)/343
    for j in range(len(magnitude)):
        var1 = (sum(((magnitude[j]-mean)**2))/(len(magnitude)-1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this (instead of your `for` loop):

```
var1 = sum([(j - mean)**2 for j in magnitude])/float(len(magnitude)-1)
```